# Is there a way to assign generic through instantiation?

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way to assign T through instantiation as in the following "hypothetical" example:

```
MyObject DummyObject = new MyObject(); 
DummyObject.MyNestedObject  = new MySecondObject<string>()

public class MyObject //**Normally is specified as MyObject<T>** 
{   
    public MySecondObject<T> MyNestedObject { get; set; } 
}
```

I want to define T on instantiation of MySecondObject. I dont want to define it in MyObject.

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: Aside from anything else, you're never declaring a type parameter T...

Comment: It is not possible but for sure what are you trying to do can be resolved in other way.

Comment: I want to define T on instantiation of MySecondObject. I dont want to define it in MyObject.

Comment: Then use solution provided by Selman22.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to declare `T` in your class. Otherwise `T` won't exist in that context.

```
public class MyObject<T>
```

Another way would be to create an interface, implement it in your `MySecondObject` generic class.Then make the property type to interface instead of `MySecondObject<T>`

```
interface IMyInterface
{

}

class MySecondObject<T> : IMyInterface
{

}

public class MyObject
{   
    public IMyInterface MyNestedObject { get; set; } 
}
```